# Workaround Perl regexp limit?

Tags: regex, perl, size

I wrote a program to extract attachments from mail folders (
[GITHUB](https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-extract-attachments.pl)) 
but it fails because of Perl's 32767 line limit on regex matching. My 
program loads each mail message as a single string, and then tries to 
match each base64-encoded file as a single string.

To replicate the problem, first do this:

```
(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=2000 count=1000 | base64 ; echo "\n\n\n" ; dd if=/dev/urandom bs=2000 count=1000 | base64 ) >! /tmp/testfile.txt
```

This creates a single 5403516 byte file that contains the 
base64-encoding of two files with a triple newline buffer between 
them. The situation in production is a little more complex, but this 
simpler case demonstrates the problem.

Our goal is to extract the base64-encoding of the first file. In other 
words, all consecutive lines that are 50 characters or longer and 
contain only base64 characters, but stopping when we see the first "=" 
sign (which indicates end-of-file in base64).

/tmp/testfile.txt has 70180 lines, with the first 35088 lines 
representing the string we want to capture (the base64-encode of the 
first file).

We now do the following in Perl:

```
# next 4 lines: read the entire file into a single variable 
undef $/; 
open(A,"/tmp/testfile.txt"); 
$all = <A>; 
close(A); 

# the output of base64 consists of these characters (plus "=" and 
# "\n", but those two are special cases) 
my($chars) = "[a-zA-Z0-9\+\/]"; 

# we declare a subroutine for testing 
sub foo {print STDERR length($_[0]),"\n";} 

# this is what I tried to do originally 
$all=~s/(\n($chars{50,}\=*\n)+)($chars+\=*\n)/foo("$1$3")/seg;
```

The above yields "2523137" then "178467" then "2523137" then "178544" 
to the STDERR.

In other words, it captures the first 2523137 characters of the first 
file, then the next 178467 characters of the first file, instead of 
capturing all 2701604 characters of the first file like I want. Note 
that 2523137 is approximately 77*32767 (and each line of 
/tmp/testfile.txt is 77 characters long).

@ikegami, if I understand correctly, your approach is:

```
$all=~s/((\n($chars{50,}\=*\n){0,20000})+)($chars+\=*\n)//seg;
```

In other words, capture 20000 lines at a time (avoiding the 32767 line 
limit), but capture multiple bunches of 20000 lines. Is this correct?

Since the results will come out in multiple variables, I didn't pass 
the result to foo(), but instead printed the results to STDERR like 
this:

```
print STDERR "1 is $1\n"; 
print STDERR "2 is $2\n"; 
print STDERR "3 is $3\n"; 
print STDERR "4 is $4\n"; 
print STDERR "5 is $5\n"; 
print STDERR "6 is $6\n";
```

This yields $1 and $2 as identical 15085 line variables, $3 and $4 as 
non-identical one line variables, and $5 and $6 as empty.

Thus, I think I misunderstood your approach. Help?

Comment: what's wrong with going line-by-line, if I can ask?

Comment: Have you tried one of the numerous Perl modules on CPAN that handle mail and attachments?

Comment: @Andy Lester I have tried several, but the main problems are 1) they don't handle nested MIME attachment well, and 2) you can never seem to recover the original message, character-for-character, after using one of these modules. I tested my program by rewriting the original message and diff'ing (see bc-check-extract-attachments.pl). In other words, I guess I find the Perl modules sloppy.

Comment: @dave Nothing really, but I wrote the program one way and don't want 
to rewrite it (laziness).

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what is limited? It's hard to work around something when you don't specify what to work around!

Comment: `/a{0,40000}/` ⇒ `/(?:a{0,20000}){2}/`?

Comment: @ikegami And the captured string would end up in $1 and $2? Hmmm, tested?

Comment: Fine, sorry. Anyway, they both match exactly the same string, so if you were to add captures, they would capture exactly the same string.

Comment: OK, everyone, I've rewritten the question entirely, hopefully clarifying it.

Comment: I'm surprised you're having trouble with the MIME modules. Are you sure the problem isn't with the original emails? Do you have a sample? I'm highly skeptical that going it alone will produce something more reliable than an existing MIME module.

Comment: Which mail modules have you tried?  There's a great many of them and navigating them successfully can be difficult.

Comment: If you're running up against this limit it's time to re-evaluate the choices you made. This is a classic case of trying to solve a problem with REGEXP and now having two problems.

Comment: "=" is not the base64 end-marker, there is none. It's for padding, and will not always be present (approx 1/3 of the time). Change "count" to 999 to see. I have used MIME::Tools extensively, as used by MimeDefang, it's easy and robust. To solve your regexp problem you should parse line by line. The only checks you can apply are valid characters [a-zA-Z0-9/+], one or two = may only appear at the end, and input length (multiple of 4). Line length is not necessarily 50 characters.

Comment: Ack! You're right about the "=" sign. Apparently, I suck more than I thought. The minimum 50-character length is just what I was seeing in my mailbox, although I realize lines can be shorter.

Comment: If you're doing regexes on very large strings, you might want to consider a regex engine that has better worst-case behavior than perl's. Perl's regex system is optimized for expressiveness rather than worst-case performance. More discussion here: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=597262 An example of a library with better worst-case performance is libregexp9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can split your base64 pieces by a static string, you can use `$/` to split up the file much more efficiently and then choose whether each piece matches your criterion.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $is_base64 = qr{^[a-zA-Z0-9\+\/]+\n?$}m;

{
    open(my $fh,"/tmp/testfile.txt");
    local $/ = "=\n";

    while(my $base64 = <$fh>) {
        chomp $base64;
        _strip(\$base64);
        next unless $base64 =~ $is_base64;

        print STDERR length $base64, "\n";
    }
}

sub _strip {
    my $ref = shift;
    $$ref =~ s{^\s+}{};
    $$ref =~ s{\s+$}{};

    return;
}
```

This is also handy for splitting up mailboxes, set `$/` to `"\n\nFrom "`.

But the comments suggesting that you should be doing this with a module are correct.  There's *a lot* of mail modules on CPAN so it can be a bit difficult to find the right one.

Comment: OK, you (plural) win. I'll rewrite this to work line-by-line.

Comment: I agree its very frustrating to hit arbitrary limits in a system. FWIW, in my 18 years of Perl I've never hit that one before. So... congratulations? :)

Comment: Yeah, I think Perl's philosophy is that there should be no arbitrary limits... if there's enough CPU and memory, anything is possible. Unfortunately, even Perl itself has to be coded in a language without that philosophy.