# Decompose large mailboxes by extracting base64-encoded lines

Tags: email

This is the actual problem I was trying to solve at 
[Workaround Perl regexp limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514166/workaround-perl-regexp-limit) 
but my question wasn't broad enough.

I use Alpine to read mail, but have several mailboxes that are 100s of 
megabytes in size. Alpine handles them fairly well, but doing "search 
all text" is slow, and even using "grep" on the mailboxes (files) 
directly can be slow.

Most of this size is due to base64 attachments. I don't really need 
base64 attachments in my mailbox, since I can't usefully search for 
text in them.

I want to remove the base64-encoded attachments from my mailbox, store 
them in separate files, and replace the attachment with "[attachment 
is now at /usr/attachments/somefile]".

Note that I actually want to store the base64-encoding in 
"somefile". I do NOT want to decode it first. Why? Base64-decoding 
broken attachments loses information. In other words, base64-decoding 
a broken attachment and then re-encoding it might yield a different 
string.

I want the ability to reconstitute my mailbox as it was, 
character-for-character, before I "decomposed" the attachments. This 
is useful for sha1 checking and my overall paranoia.

In other words, I want to move the bulky and helpful base64-encoded 
attachments out of my mailbox, but without losing a single character.

My seriously failed attempt is at [GITHUB](https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-extract-attachments.pl)

Comment: So.... what problem are you having?

Comment: I want to know if anyone's already written a program like this, or suggestions on how to write one, since my attempt pretty much failed.

Comment: Where does it fail? What error are you getting?

Comment: Oh, all of that is in the URL I linked (not the github link, the stack link). Should I re-iterate it here?

Comment: Yes please. We're lazy, help us help you ;)

Comment: Ok, I took a look at the other question and I have just one question - do you have to do it in Perl? Sounds like you just need a parser to register start and end of Base64 encoded file and cut that out to be pasted into a file of it's own, to be decoded later. Right?

Comment: That's exactly correct. In fact, the problem is really more about file inclusion/transclusion that it is about mailboxes specifically. I want to "decompose" a file a certain way, and rebuild it later. No, it doesn't have to be in Perl, that's just the language I know best. If there's an existing tool that does this, I'm happy to use it. I sometimes wonder if flex/bison could so something like this.

Comment: Flex/bison is the combo i'd recommend since you need any sort of DOM parser, and it sounds like your main issue is getting the whole string between a known start and expectable end (=)

Comment: Quite sadly, someone in the other question pointed out that not all BASE64 attachments end in "=". However, it's still a string parsing problem. The issue: I know nothing about flex/bison except that they're GNU versions of lex/yacc, which I also have no idea what they do. I sense it would be easier to write this in a language I know (especially if i want to modify it) than one that I don't.

Comment: fair enough, lex/yacc are overkill for what you are trying to do as you don't need to recognize individual tokens, you just need to know when to start and when to stop reading characters.

Maybe a 'simple' C function will do. strtok() ?